# How to convert a specific datagridview column values to double in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

Anyone knows how can I convert specific `datagridview` column values to double using `dataGridView1_CellValidating` (or using other events) in C#? 
Please help. Thank you

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    // for example I want to Validate column4 values if it is not a double then convert it to double.
}
```

Comment: do you want to change the Value of Column4 to double?

Comment: @ جمشید کامران . yes please. any idea?

Comment: Your sample code doesn't have much relevant information to your question. What do you want to do with this function? Why do you want to convert inside a validation method? Validate method `should` return true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the formatting when you initialize your column and avoid any events.

If you are using the designer simply set the `Format` property of the column to `N2`.  To get to a columns `Format` property you must highlight your grid.  Then open your columns collection window and select the column you want to change.

[image]

Under the `Appearance` category you will need to click the `DefaultCellStyle` property and then set the `Format` property to `N2`.

[image]

If you are creating the columns dynamically then set this property after initializing the column:

```
var dgTextBoxCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
dgTextBoxCol.Name = "yourColumnName";
dgTextBoxCol.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //Write in the array massive numbers from сolumn numOfcolumn
        int numOfcolumn = 3; //for example
        if (numOfcolumn > this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount) numOfcolumn = this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
        double[] massive = new double[this.dataGridView1.RowCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        massive[i] = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[numOfcolumn].Value != null ? Convert.ToDouble(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[numOfcolumn].Value.ToString()) : 0.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is How you can Set a Double Value in datagridcell

```
double value = double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value = value.ToString("N2");
```

`ToString("N2")` will format the double value with two Decimal places